# How do I maintain the aspect ratio while resizing a d3 svg shape by dragging the corner?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a svg shape workspace where you can drag, rotate, and resize different shapes. I've attached a minimal reproduction.

I want to maintain the aspect ratio of a shape while drag resizing. The implementation I have so far does this correctly for the sides, but not for the corners. I've tried a few false starts at a fix already, so I thought I might as well ask you guys:

How do I maintain the aspect ratio of a shape while resizing it by dragging a corner resize handle?

I made it so the opposite resize handle is fixed in place when you're resizing as I find this to be the most natural and least surprising. So the E resize handle is fixed in place when dragging W, and NW is fixed when dragging SE. This needs to be the case even if the aspect ratio of the shape itself is locked while resizing.

It works as intended if you hold shift while resizing on figma.com:
[image: figma resize demo]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    let x = 300;
    let y = 100;
    let width = 180;
    let height = 120;
    let rotationAngle = 0;

    const ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS = 10;
    const ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN = 12;

    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 600)
      .attr('height', 400)
      .style('background-color', 'lightgray');

    const shapeGroup = svg.append('g')
      .call(
        d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onDrag())
      );

    const rectangle = shapeGroup.append('rect')
      .attr('fill', 'rebeccapurple');

    const rotationGroup = shapeGroup
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,-2)')
      .call(
        d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onRotation())
      );

    const deviceRotationLine = rotationGroup
      .append('line')
      .style('outline','1px solid darkblue');

    const deviceRotationCircle = rotationGroup
      .append('circle')
      .style('fill','darkblue')
      .style('cursor','grab');

    const deviceRotationAngleLabel = shapeGroup
      .append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('fill','darkblue')
      .attr('alignment-baseline', 'central');

    const resizeGroup = shapeGroup.append('g');

    const resizeHandles = [
      ['NW', 'N', 'NE'],
      ['W', undefined, 'E'],
      ['SW', 'S', 'SE']
    ].map((resizeHandleRow) => {
      return resizeHandleRow.map((handle) => {
        if (!handle) {
            return undefined;
        }
        const resizeCursors = {
        'NW': 'nwse-resize',
        'N': 'ns-resize',
        'NE': 'nesw-resize',
        'W': 'ew-resize',
        'E': 'ew-resize',
        'SW': 'nesw-resize',
        'S': 'ns-resize',
        'SE': 'nwse-resize'
      }

      const resizeHandle = resizeGroup
        .append('rect')
        .attr('width', 8 * 2)
        .attr('height', 8 * 2)
        .attr('x', -8)
        .attr('y', -8)
        .attr('cursor', resizeCursors[handle])
        .attr('fill', 'fuchsia')
        .call(
          d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onResize(handle))
        );

        return resizeHandle;
      });
    });

    function onRotation() {

      function angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians(point1, point2) {
        if (point1[0] === point2[0] && point1[1] === point2[1]) {
          return Math.PI / 2;
        }
        return Math.atan2(point2[1] - point1[1], point2[0] - point1[0]);
      }

      function radiansToDegrees(radians) {
        return radians / (Math.PI / 180);
      }

      function normalizeAngle(angle) {
        return Math.round((angle + 360) % 360);
      }

      const rotateHandleVerticalPos = (height / 2) + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN;

      let deltaAngleRadians = angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians([0, 0], [d3.event.x, d3.event.y]);
      deltaAngleRadians = deltaAngleRadians - angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians([0, 0], [0, -rotateHandleVerticalPos]);

      const deltaAngleDegrees = radiansToDegrees(deltaAngleRadians);
      rotationAngle = normalizeAngle(rotationAngle + deltaAngleDegrees);

      renderShape();
    }

    function onResize(handle) {
      const event = d3.event;

      const heightOverWidth = height / width;
      const widthOverHeight = width / height;

      const oldX = x;
      const oldY = y;
      const oldWidth = width;
      const oldHeight = height;

      switch (handle) {
        case 'N':
          height += event.y * -1;
          y += event.y / 2;
          width += event.y * widthOverHeight * -1;
          break;

        case 'NE':
          width += event.dx;
          height += event.y * -1;
          x += event.dx / 2;
          y += event.y / 2;
          break;

        case 'E':
          width += event.dx;
          x += event.dx / 2;
          height += event.dx * heightOverWidth;
          break;

        case 'SE':
          width += event.dx;
          height += event.dy;
          x += event.dx / 2;
          y += event.dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'S':
          height += event.dy;
          width += event.dy * widthOverHeight;
          y += event.dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'SW':
          width += event.x * -1;
          height += event.dy;
          x += event.x / 2;
          y += event.dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'W':
          width += event.x * -1;
          x += event.x / 2;
          height += event.x * heightOverWidth * -1;
          break;

        case 'NW':
          width += event.x * -1;
          height += event.y * -1;
          x += event.x / 2;
          y += event.y / 2;
          break;
      }

      // Enforce min width & height
      if (width <= 50 || height <= 50) {
        x = oldX;
        y = oldY;
        width = oldWidth;
        height = oldHeight;
      }

      renderShape();
    }

    function onDrag() {
      x += d3.event.dx;
      y += d3.event.dy;

      renderShape();
    }

    function renderShape() {
      shapeGroup
        .attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y}) rotate(${rotationAngle})`);

      rectangle
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('transform', `translate(${-(width/2)}, ${-(height/2)})`);

      resizeGroup.attr('transform', `translate(${-(width/2)}, ${-(height/2)})`)

      // Render resize handles
      for (const [i, row] of resizeHandles.entries()) {
        const offsetY = height * (i / 2);

        for (const [j, handle] of row.entries()) {
          if (handle) {
            const offsetX = width * (j / 2);
            handle.attr('transform', `translate(${offsetX}, ${offsetY})`);
          }
        }
      }

      // Render rotation handle
      const rotateHandleVerticalPos = height / 2 + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN;

      deviceRotationLine
        .attr('y1', -rotateHandleVerticalPos)
        .attr('y2', -(height / 2));

      deviceRotationCircle
        .attr('cy', -(rotateHandleVerticalPos + ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS))
        .attr('r', ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS);

      deviceRotationAngleLabel
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' +
            (ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS * 3) + ','
            + -(rotateHandleVerticalPos + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN) +
          ') rotate(' +
            -rotationAngle +
          ')'
        )
        .text(rotationAngle + String.fromCharCode(176));
    }

    renderShape();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting width and height using the viewBox attribute?

Comment: viewBox is only for the svg dom element itself, right? Maybe I wasn't clear in my question: I want to maintain the aspect ratio of a shape inside my svg element workspace.

Comment: I've seen it implemented before. E.g. diagrams.net and Libreoffice Draw. In both you hold the shift button while resizing to lock the aspect ratio. But I see that diagrams.net kinda cheats by only scaling one axis while dragging a corner. Its a nicely simple workaround though. I would love to see a solution that does something like what Libreoffice Draw does though.

Comment: I added a gif of it working as intended on figma.com

Answer (score -1):

Just clamp the `dx/dy` pair to fit the original aspect ratio. Take SE handle for example:

```js
case "SE": {
  const shiftKey = event.sourceEvent.shiftKey;
  let { dx, dy } = event;

  if (shiftKey) {
    if (dx / dy > widthOverHeight) {
      // dx exceed original ratio
      dx = widthOverHeight * dy;
    } else if (dy / dx > heightOverWidth) {
      // dy exceed original ratio
      dy = dx * heightOverWidth;
    }
  }

  width += dx;
  height += dy;
  x += dx / 2;
  y += dy / 2;

  break;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me unfortunately. I tried pasting this into my example and holding shift while clicking and dragging the SE handle and it didn't lock the aspect ratio for me.

Answer (score -2):

Extending from @hackape's answer. You don't need to check any condition when the shift key is pressed. Instead, directly change the necessary width, height, x, y value depending on the handle value. Handle for `SE` is in example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>

    let x = 300;
    let y = 100;
    let width = 180;
    let height = 120;
    let rotationAngle = 0;

    const ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS = 10;
    const ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN = 12;

    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', 600)
      .attr('height', 400)
      .style('background-color', 'lightgray');

    const shapeGroup = svg.append('g')
      .call(
        d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onDrag())
      );

    const rectangle = shapeGroup.append('rect')
      .attr('fill', 'rebeccapurple');

    const rotationGroup = shapeGroup
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,-2)')
      .call(
        d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onRotation())
      );

    const deviceRotationLine = rotationGroup
      .append('line')
      .style('outline','1px solid darkblue');

    const deviceRotationCircle = rotationGroup
      .append('circle')
      .style('fill','darkblue')
      .style('cursor','grab');

    const deviceRotationAngleLabel = shapeGroup
      .append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('fill','darkblue')
      .attr('alignment-baseline', 'central');

    const resizeGroup = shapeGroup.append('g');

    const resizeHandles = [
      ['NW', 'N', 'NE'],
      ['W', undefined, 'E'],
      ['SW', 'S', 'SE']
    ].map((resizeHandleRow) => {
      return resizeHandleRow.map((handle) => {
        if (!handle) {
            return undefined;
        }
        const resizeCursors = {
        'NW': 'nwse-resize',
        'N': 'ns-resize',
        'NE': 'nesw-resize',
        'W': 'ew-resize',
        'E': 'ew-resize',
        'SW': 'nesw-resize',
        'S': 'ns-resize',
        'SE': 'nwse-resize'
      }

      const resizeHandle = resizeGroup
        .append('rect')
        .attr('width', 8 * 2)
        .attr('height', 8 * 2)
        .attr('x', -8)
        .attr('y', -8)
        .attr('cursor', resizeCursors[handle])
        .attr('fill', 'fuchsia')
        .call(
          d3.drag()
          .on('drag', () => onResize(handle))
        );

        return resizeHandle;
      });
    });

    function onRotation() {

      function angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians(point1, point2) {
        if (point1[0] === point2[0] && point1[1] === point2[1]) {
          return Math.PI / 2;
        }
        return Math.atan2(point2[1] - point1[1], point2[0] - point1[0]);
      }

      function radiansToDegrees(radians) {
        return radians / (Math.PI / 180);
      }

      function normalizeAngle(angle) {
        return Math.round((angle + 360) % 360);
      }

      const rotateHandleVerticalPos = (height / 2) + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN;

      let deltaAngleRadians = angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians([0, 0], [d3.event.x, d3.event.y]);
      deltaAngleRadians = deltaAngleRadians - angleBetweenTwoPointsRadians([0, 0], [0, -rotateHandleVerticalPos]);

      const deltaAngleDegrees = radiansToDegrees(deltaAngleRadians);
      rotationAngle = normalizeAngle(rotationAngle + deltaAngleDegrees);

      renderShape();
    }

    function onResize(handle) {
      const event = d3.event;

      const heightOverWidth = height / width;
      const widthOverHeight = width / height;

      const oldX = x;
      const oldY = y;
      const oldWidth = width;
      const oldHeight = height;
      const shiftKey = event.sourceEvent.shiftKey;
      let { dx, dy } = event;
      switch (handle) {
        case 'N':
          height += event.y * -1;
          y += event.y / 2;
          width += event.y * widthOverHeight * -1;
          break;

        case 'NE':
          width += event.dx;
          height += event.y * -1;
          x += event.dx / 2;
          y += event.y / 2;
          break;

        case 'E':
          width += event.dx;
          x += event.dx / 2;
          height += event.dx * heightOverWidth;
          break;

        case 'SE':
          if (shiftKey) {
              dx = widthOverHeight * dy;
              dy = dx * heightOverWidth;
          }

          width += dx;
          height += dy;
          x += dx / 2;
          y += dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'S':
          height += event.dy;
          width += event.dy * widthOverHeight;
          y += event.dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'SW':
          width += event.x * -1;
          height += event.dy;
          x += event.x / 2;
          y += event.dy / 2;
          break;

        case 'W':
          width += event.x * -1;
          x += event.x / 2;
          height += event.x * heightOverWidth * -1;
          break;

        case 'NW':
          width += event.x * -1;
          height += event.y * -1;
          x += event.x / 2;
          y += event.y / 2;
          break;
      }

      // Enforce min width & height
      if (width <= 50 || height <= 50) {
        x = oldX;
        y = oldY;
        width = oldWidth;
        height = oldHeight;
      }

      renderShape();
    }

    function onDrag() {
      x += d3.event.dx;
      y += d3.event.dy;

      renderShape();
    }

    function renderShape() {
      shapeGroup
        .attr('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y}) rotate(${rotationAngle})`);

      rectangle
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('transform', `translate(${-(width/2)}, ${-(height/2)})`);

      resizeGroup.attr('transform', `translate(${-(width/2)}, ${-(height/2)})`)

      // Render resize handles
      for (const [i, row] of resizeHandles.entries()) {
        const offsetY = height * (i / 2);

        for (const [j, handle] of row.entries()) {
          if (handle) {
            const offsetX = width * (j / 2);
            handle.attr('transform', `translate(${offsetX}, ${offsetY})`);
          }
        }
      }

      // Render rotation handle
      const rotateHandleVerticalPos = height / 2 + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN;

      deviceRotationLine
        .attr('y1', -rotateHandleVerticalPos)
        .attr('y2', -(height / 2));

      deviceRotationCircle
        .attr('cy', -(rotateHandleVerticalPos + ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS))
        .attr('r', ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS);

      deviceRotationAngleLabel
        .attr(
          'transform',
          'translate(' +
            (ROTATION_HANDLE_RADIUS * 3) + ','
            + -(rotateHandleVerticalPos + ROTATION_HANDLE_MARGIN) +
          ') rotate(' +
            -rotationAngle +
          ')'
        )
        .text(rotationAngle + String.fromCharCode(176));
    }

    renderShape();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't drag in both x and y direction like the example in the question description.